# How to save and restore checkbox properly in pyqt

Tags: python, qt, checkbox, pyqt

I am saving my ui checkbox state on application close and restoring it on application open.

This is my call during the close event:

```
settings.setValue("checkBoxReplace", self.ui.checkBoxReplace.checkState());
```

This is my call during the ui initialize:

```
value = settings.value("checkBoxReplace").toInt()[0]   # ??? works, but is there a more proper way?
self.ui.checkBoxReplace.setCheckState(value)   # restore checkbox
```

The above calls work, but I wonder if I am reading the stored QVariant properly?  I used toInt, but it returns 2 values.

Comment: It's done similarily in C++. The only difference is that in pyqt `QVariant::toInt` returns int value and boolean ok flag while in C++ ok flag is retrieved using pointer argument. So yes, your code seems to be quite correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has already been pointed out, in PyQt `QVariant.toInt` returns a tuple of the value, plus a flag indicating whether the conversion was successful. So your code is perfectly correct as it is.

However, it's worth pointing out that you can eliminate these `QVariant` conversions altogether by adding the following at the start of your program:

```
import sip
sip.setapi('QVariant', 2)
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
```

With this in place, any Qt method that returns a `QVariant` will return a python type instead (this is only needed for python2; python3 has this behaviour by default). And it is also possible to eliminate `QString` in the same way - see the [docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/incompatible_apis.html) for more details.

PS: if you're going to go down this route, you should probably also take a look at the [Support for QSettings](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/pyqt_qsettings.html) section in the PyQt docs.